# mongodb add a new field to an existing array with python

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, pymongo, robo3t

Collection in database:

```
'_id' : ObjectId("sdhsndi66822dsxsd"),
'values' : {
        "ping" : [ 
            {
                "key" : "5ef9ac6eb1272e16729b17f6",
                "name" : "sdsadsadsa"
            },
           {
                "key" : "5ef9ac6eb1272e16729b17f6",
                "name" : "sdsadsadsa"
            }
              ]
           }
```

Here I need to add/update a new key value pair. So the expected output should be:

```
'_id' : ObjectId("sdhsndi66822dsxsd"),
    'values' : {
            "ping" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "5ef9ac6eb1272e16729b17f6",
                    "name" : "sdsadsadsa",
                    "new":"added_new"
                },
               {
                    "key" : "5ef9ac6eb1272e16729b17f6",
                    "name" : "sdsadsadsa",
                    "new":"added_new"
                }
                  ]
               }
```

I need to achieve this with pymongo(mongo query also helpful). I have tried using $addtoset but doesnot help.

Comment: If you answer helps you please tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$addFields`.

```
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      "values.ping.new": "added_new"
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y8OrRHfbfbv)